# How to setup basic Rails models associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hey guys im working on a application where a devise user sign ups and logs in, Once the user logs in they can 'create a team' or 'join a team'. I have my associations set up like this

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable 
   validates_presence_of :phone, :city, :state, :street, :zip, presence: true, on: :create

   belongs_to :team      
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :users   
end
```

and my tables are set up

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "team_name"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string "firstname"
  t.integer "team_id"
  t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

**team_controller.rb**

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
     @team = current_user.team
   end

   def new_team

   end

   def create_team
     @team = current_user.create_team(sanitize_team)
     if @team.save 
       redirect_to team_root_path
     else
       render json: @team.errors.full_messages
     end
   end

   def join_team 
     @teams = Team.all
   end

   def team

   end

   private 

   def sanitize_team
     params.require(:team).permit(:team_name, :team_statement)
   end
end
```

I want the users 'team_id' attribute to update with the teams id when they create a team. or when they join a team. Are my associations correct? how would i make this happen in the controller ?

Comment: What do your routes look like? Are you using Rail's default RESTful routes (i.e. `resources :teams` in your routes.rb file? There is no need to create actions like new_team, create_team, etc. Instead, team will be implied by the name of the controller and you should simply have new, create, etc. actions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, associations are correct. You can do it better only by adding foreign key to your database schema. It can be done by generator `rails g migration AddTeamToUsers team:references`

More information about associations can be found here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

In controller you have to change only the whitelisting params to allow `team_id`. And you probably need to add to your form in view something like this: 

`<%= f.select :team_id, Team.all.map { |t| [t.team_name, t.id] } %>`

Comment: @DonPaulid thanks for the quick reply currently when i create a team as a user the team_id column is not updating with the proper team id that it belongs to. but the record is saved in the database.

Comment: @kevinlopez Try to add `validates :team_id, :team, presence: true`. maybe it will help you. Team_id validates presence of a number, :team validates existence of the team in the database,.

Answer (score 1):

Let's strip your code example down to the minimum required:

```
# app/models/team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end

# db/migrate/20181124230131_create_teams.rb
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :team_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# db/migrate/20181124230136_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :team
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
team = Team.where(team_name: 'foo').first_or_create!
team.users << current_user
```

Comment: i have my tables made already, but when i create a team as a user that teams id is not updated on my user table, and i already added 'team_id' column

Comment: im going to include my controller in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the association up as optional:

```
class User < ApplicationController 
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
end
```

Otherwise the validations on the user model will not let the user be saved without a team.

Then setup the teams resource:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :teams do
  post :join
end
```

`post :join` creates an additional `POST /teams/:team_id/join` route.

Then setup the controller:

```
class TeamsController

  # ...

  # GET /teams/new
  def new
    @team = Team.find
  end

  # POST /teams
  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)
    if @team.save
      unless current_user.team
        current_user.update(team: @team)
      end
      redirect_to 'somewhere'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  def join
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    if current_user.update(team: @team)
      redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team joined'
    else
      redirect_to @team, error: 'Could not join team'
    end
  end

  #

  private
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:team_name, :team_statement)
    end 
end
```

Note that prefixing your action names is neither needed nor compatible with the "Rails way". Prefixing column names is also largely superfluous.